# How can I repair a power cable with missing jacket insulation?

Tags: wiring

About 1 inch of the cable jacket is missing. The inner copper wires are intact and insulated.

Can I repair the yellow shield with an acceptable tape or shrink wrap? I need to pass an inspection and want to do it properly within code.

Comment: I take it we are talking about a NM cable here in a dry, indoor environment?

Answer (score 3):

The jacket needs to enter the box 1/4"  if it is missing further back than that the inspector may allow heat shrink but I would probably replace that run so I wouldn't have to wait for another inspection unless you call them and they say heat shrink would be acceptable. Code reference NEC 314.7.C.

Answer (score -3):

Where is this wire? Are you referring to the end of it, in a switch or receptacle or junction box? If so, don't worry about it. The "jacket" is there mostly to protect the actual wire insulation from being damaged during installation. Once it's installed, the jacket is unnecessary.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading you wrong, but this is incorrect. The cable jacket must remain intact until inside a junction box.

Comment: Yeah, that is not true, if it was we could install THHN, carefully.