# Can cables entering a box have their sheath removed short of the box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, basement

I have been in this house for several years, and have just a bit of exposed copper wiring coming out of the upper left side of this blue electrical box in the basement.  The box connects to the outlet above and to the right, which a washing machine is plugged into.

Does the exposed copper wire present a fire or shock hazard? If so, can I fix this with electrical tape, or is something else required?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Many thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/156304/35141

Answer (score 9):

This is unsafe, though not at this moment from the exposed wire. That copper wire is the ground wire, which carries current back to the panel only when the power wire has a fault and gets power to the grounding system of the appliances or wiring past this box. When this happens (barring other failures closer to the panel) it is a short circuit, and the circuit breaker pops.

This situation is unsafe because the yellow sheath of the cable is supposed to be inside the blue box for some small distance. Code requires 6mm or 1/4" of sheath inside the box, per Ecnerwal's comment below.

If there is slack somewhere on that cable, you can turn power off to the cable's circuit at the circuit breaker. Then carefully re-arrange the cable so the slack is next to the box. Then take the device in the box out, pull the cable through so the sheath is inside the box, then bundle up the black, white, and bare wires more and put the device back in the box.

If you don't have enough slack to do this, you may have to add a junction box to the cable somewhere where the covered junction box can remain visible and accessible with only a screwdriver. Then extend the cable with another piece of the same gauge so the sheath is inside the blue box.

Another solution that our resident electrical masters may know more about might be possible, if there is enough unsheathed black/white/bare wire inside the box already (I think code requires 6 inches of unsheathed wire inside the box). You may be able to wrap the unsheathed part outside the box and part-way into the box with special self-sealing electric tape that has a voltage rating equal to or greater than the cable's voltage rating. This would extend the sheath into the box.

Comment: I would also properly staple the cable to the stud when its in the proper position.

Comment: Yes judging by the other picture you have a lot of slack.

Answer (score 8):

That bare wire should only carry current during ground fault and the breaker should trip before the bare wire gets hot enough to start a fire. I suspect what has happened is the wire was inserted into the box when installed, but lack of proper support has allowed the cable to get snagged and has pulled the cable out of the box.

It's not up to Code. The NEC states rules, then often follows with exceptions. The normal code requirement is to support [NM cable every 4.5 ft. and within 12 in. of entering box](https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/3/wiring-methods-and-materials#334.30) with not more  than 18" of cable looped between the support and the box.

The Code also requires the 1/4" of sheathing enter the box, and the cable be secured to the box, but has a significant exception that applies:

> **314.17(B)(2) Cables Entering Through Cable Clamps.** Where cable assemblies with nonmetallic sheaths are used, the sheath shall extend
> not less than 6 mm (1/4 in.) inside the box and 6 mm (1/4 in.) beyond
> the end of any cable clamp. Except as covered in 300.15(C), the wiring
> method shall be secured to the box or conduit body.
>
> Exception: Where
> nonmetallic-sheathed cable is used with single gang nonmetallic boxes
> not larger than a nominal size 57 mm × 100 mm (21/4 in. × 4 in.)
> mounted in walls or ceilings, and where the cable is fastened within
> 200 mm (8 in.) of the box measured along the sheath and where the
> sheath extends through a cable knockout not less than 6 mm (1/4 in.),
> securing the cable to the box shall not be required. Multiple cable
> entries shall be permitted in a single cable knockout opening.

Your box appears to be the type of box with knockouts that requires the support distance to be reduced to within 8" of the box.

It looks like you have significant slack in the cable. Just pushing the wire back into the box is not a great idea because the bar ground wire my fold poorly and contact a hot terminal in the j-box.

All you should have to do turn the power off. Staple the cable to the stud within 12" of the metal upper metal box. Remove the receptacle from the lower plastic junction box and draw enough cable into the box to have at least 1/4" of undamaged sheathing in the box. Staple the cable to the stud within 8" of box as allowed/required by the exception. Then if necessary trim the wires inside the plastic junction box to reinstall the receptacle. It's hard to tell from the picture but I think your staples will cover the 4.5 ft. support requirement, but a third staple may be required between the two staples near the boxes.

If the cable isn't long enough to reach the easiest route may be to replace the cable.

Answer (score 5):

Not safe. But not a huge deal to resolve.

The bare copper is a ground wire. That does *not* normally carry any current. If things are wired correctly in the rest of the house (but which is *not* always the case) then you can touch it with no concerns at all.

But this is absolutely not to code. A non-metallic cable - a.k.a., NM cable or Romex (common brand name) - is supposed to have a clamp to hold it in place where it enters the box. With a metal box that can be added at any time, but not with most plastic boxes.

Since there is some slack in the left cable (the one that is split open before it enters the box, the fix is simple:

- Remove whatever is inside the box from the other side.
- Remove the plastic box
- Install a metal box, such as this [example from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-4-in-H-x-2-in-W-x-2-1-8-in-D-Steel-Metallic-1-Gang-Drawn-Handy-Box-with-Eight-1-2-in-KO-s-and-F-Bracket-1-Pack-G19282-F-UPC/324511459):

[image: box]

In many cases I would recommend a larger box. But in this case you need a single gang box because you want the opening in the other side of the drywall to be in the same location as before to avoid having to do drywall work.

- Feed the NM cables through appropriate cable clamps installed in knockouts in the box.
- Install the receptacle or other devices that were previously in the plastic box.
- Add at least one staple (preferably two to match the other cable) to secure the left cable to the stud just like the right cable is stapled.

Comment: See NEC 314.17(B)(2) "Exception: Where nonmetallic-sheathed cable is used with single gang nonmetallic boxes ... securing the cable to the box shall not be required."

Comment: @NoSparksPlease I did **NOT** say **secure** to the box. I specifically referred to securing **to the stud** and the requirement for a **cable clamp**. The cable clamp in a plastic box is typically an integral part of the box, but in this case it appears to have been forcefully removed.

Comment: I read "*is supposed to have a clamp to hold it in place where it enters the box*" to mean a clamp is required to secure to the box. The box appears to be a Carlon B122A style box that has twist out openings that do not clamp to the cable, and the exception allows use without a clamp. https://d3501hjdis3g5w.cloudfront.net/images/products/zoom/b122a-upc-2.jpg

Comment: @NoSparksPlease I disagree. Not clear from the Carlon docs but I have found some other pages that clearly show these clamps as "break one side, the other side is a hinge, insert cable, clamp holds it in place". And in OP's picture, the clamps are totally gone.

Comment: There are definitely boxes without built-in clamps. Here's one that Home Depot sells: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-18-cu-in-1-Gang-New-Work-Electrical-Switch-Outlet-Box-BOX-NS18N/319478164 . You can see it in use with the knockouts completely removed, no clamp.

Comment: @SortofDamocles Yes, but. In the picture showing the clamps entirely removed, the cables are secured within a few inches of the box. I think it is an and/or situation - with single-gang plastic boxes you don't have to have both clamps *and* secured within 8" of the box, but you have to have at least one *or* the other.

Comment: Calling something a clamp does not make it one. The Carlon things (and similar from other brands) clamp nothing. They flop and twist with the slightest touch, if one is so careless as to leave one side still attached. Although referred to as clamps on some Carlon pages, they are called "Clean Easy Knockouts (One-Gang Only)" right next to illustration of "Integral Clamps (Multi-Gang Boxes)" in Carlon online box catalog pdf.

Answer (score 2):

That is a ground wire and should be safe.  It is there just for your safety when something goes wrong.

The cable covering should be in side the box a bit and should be fixed after turning off the breaker and making sure no power in the box with a tester.  People do turn off the wrong breaker by mistake some times and not fun to find out.

If that cable is too short to go into the box like the other cable, you can add a junction box nearby and splice a suitable length of the same new cable.